# Android paging mechanism handle

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

How do I handle paging mechanism?

I have created a code to create paging of data. But when I specify a limit that has expired, the application will be damaged and force closed.

My `paging class` :

```
public class SetPaging {
    public static final String[] PAGING = new String[] {
        "0,5","5,5","10,5","15,5","20,5"
    };
}
```

My `listener` :

```
pullRefresh = ((PullAndLoadListView) listView);
    pullRefresh.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {

    public void onLoadMore() {
        new LoadMoreData().execute();
    }
});
```

My `async code` :

```
private class LoadMoreData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            page = page + 1;
            if (page > SetPaging.PAGING.length) {
                page = 0;
            }
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            try {
                ArrayList<UtamaBean> NextUtama = new ArrayList<UtamaBean>();
                NextUtama = PushServer.getNextUtama(SetPaging.PAGING[page]);
                if (page > 0) {
                    utamabean.addAll(NextUtama);
                } else {
                    utamabean = PushServer.getNextUtama(SetPaging.PAGING[page]);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                netError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            adapter.setItem(utamabean);

            pullRefresh.onLoadMoreComplete();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            pullRefresh.onLoadMoreComplete();
        }
    }
```

All went smoothly. Only when the sixth paging applications (outside the rules **"20,5"**) then the application will be immediately force closed.

How best to conduct the sixth restrictions if paging is done, the application will not be entered into async function and request the data?

Thanks

**===UPDATE===**

My LogCat :

```
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223):    at com.joris.babe.F_Test$LoadMoreData.doInBackground(F_Test.java:156)
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223):    at com.joris.babe.F_Test$LoadMoreData.doInBackground(F_Test.java:1)
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-24 19:59:40.587: E/AndroidRuntime(16223):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: what does the log say? Any exceptions?

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this

```
netError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Updating ui from `doInbackground`.`doInbackground` is invoked on the background thread.

Hence the exception. Update ui on the ui thread. Return a value in doInbackground.  Based on the value returned set the visibility accrodingly in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Hai @Raghunandan : I have to replace the code, but I still look out on the loading screen. How can I not run `pullRefresh.setOnLoadMoreListener` the last paging?

Comment: @BerthoJoris i have not used pull to refresh so i have no idea. but your exception is bcoz you run updation of ui on the background thread

Comment: I just got a new error log. Since I opened the try catch block so that my application can display the error message. Is it still the same with you mean?

Comment: @BerthoJoris its arrayindex out of bound excpetion. length is 5. index starts from 0. So your index is out of bound. This has nothing do with Calledfromwrongthreadexception

Comment: I intentionally limit the paging on a particular array. If you look at the `paging class` above...How do I check my array to be able to stop the request if the limit has been exhausted?

Comment: @BerthoJoris i have no idea about paging or pull to refresh sorry